# docker-compose up で tty: trueを付けているのに、commandを実行するとコンテナが終わってしまう

Tags: docker-compose

いつもお世話になっております。
dockerを使ってローカル環境の作成をしております。
下記のような `docker-compose.yml` を作成しており、`command` オプションにて起動時にシェルを実行したいと思っております。

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    php:
        build: ./Dockerfiles/php
        container_name: "laravel_php"
        volumes:
            - ./src:/var/www/html
        working_dir: /var/www/html
        command: ["php", "entrypoint.sh"]
        tty: true
        stdin_open: true
```

ただ、この状態で実行をすると、下記のようにコンテナが終了してしまいます。

```
$ docker-compose up
Recreating laravel_php ... done
Attaching to laravel_php
laravel_php | 2019/01/20 07:41:14 entrypoint.sh [INFO] Connection confriming...
laravel_php exited with code 0

$ docker ps -all
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
0371439067da        laravel_php     "docker-php-entrypoi…"   11 seconds ago      Exited (0) 10 seconds ago                       laravel_php
```

entrypoint.sh の中身はテストではechoしているだけのものになり、エラー等は発生しておりません。

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo `date '+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'` $0 "[INFO] Connection confriming..."
```

`command` オプションを設定せずに `docker-compose up` は正常に起動し続けて、コンテナ内に入って、実行は出来ております。

これを、 `command` を実行した後も、起動し続けるようにしたいのですが、その方法をご教授頂きたく投稿をさせていただきました。

何卒、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

フォアグランドのプロセスが動き続ければコンテナは終了しないはずなので、下記のようにcommandを定義するのはどうでしょう。この場合は`bash`を対話モードで動かし続けます。

```
command: bash -c "bash entrypoint.sh && /bin/bash"
```

ところで、下記のcommandの定義は `php entrypoint.sh` と展開され、PHP処理系にシェルスクリプトが渡されてしまっているので、記述の誤りではないでしょうか。

```
command: ["php", "entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！ご指摘頂いたように修正しましたところ、期待通りの動きになりました。

Comment: `command: ["php", "entrypoint.sh"]` の記載は、ご指摘の通り記述のミスでした。ご指摘ありがとうございました。